# bundle command running with wrong ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I have installed 2 ruby versions on my using rbenv mac - 2.3.7 and 2.4.5

If i run command `ruby -v` following is the output:

```
ruby 2.4.5p335 (2018-10-18 revision 65137) [x86_64-darwin18]
```

But if i run `bundle install` from my project, i get following error message:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.3.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.5
```

I have used **rbenv** to install different ruby version.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a `.ruby-version` file on your project's root:

```sh
$ echo 'ruby-2.4.5' > .ruby-version
$ cd .
```

That will set your Ruby version properly.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running a version of `Bundler` that was install using a different Ruby version. You can try reinstalling `Bundler` in your project folder:

```
gem install bundler
```